# how to post-process coordinates, lat, lon, .... after retrieval of data?

Tags: perl, geocoding, cpan

When using `Geo::Coder:Google`, a mapping from an address to lat/lon works vice versa.

But the output is not suitable for an immediate access concerning concrete fields especially when converting lat/lon to an address.

According to my debug log:

loc by lat 48.308472 / lon 14.284578 --- `\ {#012    address_components   [#012        [0] {#012            long_name    "Nibelungenbrücke",#012            short_name   "B129",#012            types        [#012                [0] "route"#012            ]#012        },#012        [1] {#012            long_name    "Landstraße",#012            short_name   "Landstraße",#012            types        [#012                [0] "neighborhood",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [2] {#012            long_name    "Innenstadt",#012            short_name   "Innenstadt",#012            types        [#012                [0] "sublocality",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [3] {#012            long_name    "Linz",#012            short_name   "Linz",#012            types        [#012                [0] "locality",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [4] {#012            long_name    "Linz",#012            short_name   "Linz",#012            types        [#012                [0] "administrative_area_level_2",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [5] {#012            long_name    "Upper Austria",#012            short_name   "OÖ",#012            types        [#012                [0] "administrative_area_level_1",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [6] {#012            long_name    "Austria",#012            short_name   "AT",#012            types        [#012                [0] "country",#012                [1] "political"#012            ]#012        },#012        [7] {#012            long_name    4020,#012            short_name   4020,#012            types        [#012                [0] "postal_code"#012            ]#012        }#012    ],#012    formatted_address    "Nibelungenbrücke, 4020 Linz, Austria",#012    geometry             {#012        bounds          {#012            n`

Using substring subs would drive me nuts. Currently, the code:

```
    sub map_latlon_to_loc($$){ my $lat = shift; my $lon = shift;
          $location = $geocoder_google->reverse_geocode(latlng => $lat.','.$lon);
          dbg("loc by lat ".$lat." / lon ".$lon." --- " . p $location);
    }
```

Which concrete way / method / sub is suitable to access attributes within `$location`?

btw `p` refers to a Printer module

Have nothing seen on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~arcanez/Geo-Coder-Google-0.13/lib/Geo/Coder/Google/V3.pm), which would do the trick. It should not work only for [US](http://search.cpan.org/~sderle/Geo-Coder-US-1.00/US.pm). My implementation has to cope with any country.

Comment: ***Please*** don't use prototypes in run-of-the-mill code. Perl subroutine prototypes are very different from those in other languages and are meant to facilitate coding new operators. On the other hand, ***please always*** `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all your variables at their first point of use using `my`.

Comment: that's not from cpan. dbg was only a sub to log towards syslog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you're using to display the data returned by Google (what are `dbg` and `p`?) but it's certainly not a string: it's a complex hash containing nested hashes and arrays. Using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) to display it reveals the contents and makes them simple to access and manipulate.

This program uses a fixed-up version of your own subroutine to fetch information for the Royal Observatory in Greenwich. It then prints the `long_name` value of each line in the `address_components` array. It also dumps the entire data structure using `Data::Dump` so that you can see what is being returned.

If you prefer, the [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) may also be used. It is a core module for Perl 5 and so won't need installing, but the layout of the text it produces is inferior to that of `Data::Dump`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Geo::Coder::Google;
use Data::Dump;

my $geocoder = Geo::Coder::Google->new(apiver => 3);

my $location = map_latlon_to_loc(51.4768777, 0);

my $address = $location->{address_components};
print $_->{long_name}, "\n" for @$address;
print "\n\n";
dd $location;

sub map_latlon_to_loc {
  my ($lat, $lng) = @_;
  $geocoder->reverse_geocode(latlng => "$lat,$lng");
}
```

**output**

```
Blackheath Avenue
Greater London
United Kingdom
SE10 8XJ
London


{
  address_components => [
    {
      long_name => "Blackheath Avenue",
      short_name => "Blackheath Ave",
      types => ["route"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "Greater London",
      short_name => "Gt Lon",
      types => ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "United Kingdom",
      short_name => "GB",
      types => ["country", "political"],
    },
    {
      long_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      short_name => "SE10 8XJ",
      types => ["postal_code"],
    },
    { long_name => "London", short_name => "London", types => ["postal_town"] },
  ],
  formatted_address => "Blackheath Avenue, London SE10 8XJ, UK",
  geometry => {
    bounds        => {
                       northeast => { lat => 51.4770228, lng => 0.0005404 },
                       southwest => { lat => 51.4762273, lng => -0.0001147 },
                     },
    location      => { lat => 51.4766277, lng => 0.0002212 },
    location_type => "APPROXIMATE",
    viewport      => {
                       northeast => { lat => 51.4779740302915, lng => 0.00156183029150203 },
                       southwest => { lat => 51.4752760697085, lng => -0.00113613029150203 },
                     },
  },
  types => ["route"],
}
```